# error MT3001: Could not AOT the assembly when during MonoTouch project compilation

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, xamarin-studio

I have 2 projects in solution 1. PCL library project (PCL.dll) 2. MonoTouch project

When I'm trying to compile MonoTouch porject I get the following error:

> error MT3001: Could not AOT the assembly '../obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/Build/PCL.dll'

when I set "link sdk libraries" at MonoTouch project settings I got another error:

> MonoTouch Trial version 6.4.0 using framework: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.1.sdk error MT2002: Failed to resolve "System.Linq.Expressions.ConstantExpression System.Linq.Expressions.Expression::Constant(System.Object)" reference from "System.Linq.Expressions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"

I don't use LINQ and have no references to Syste.Linq.Expressions.

Comment: Are you using any third-party assemblies? Those could also bring in System.Linq.Expressions.dll.